# tel:// scheme automatically formats the phone number

Tags: ios, swift

I trying to make a phone call with this sample number 639450200901 but it seems iOS sdk automatically formats the phone number. Displaying like this one "+63 945 020 0901" on the alert. Any suggestions for this not to be automatically formatted, i wanted to proceed with the call without this + sign? Here is my sample code:

```
if let phoneNum = _params["recipient"] as? String,
           let percentEncodedString = phoneNum.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed),
           let url = URL(string: "tel:\(percentEncodedString)") {
        
            if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)) {
                   UIApplication.shared.open(phoneNumUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: { ( completed ) in
                      print("Call completed")
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the 10.3 release notes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/

> **openURL**
>
> When a third party application invokes openURL: on a tel://,
> facetime://, or facetime-audio:// URL, iOS displays a prompt and
> requires user confirmation before dialing.

So, when you invoke a URL with scheme tel://, phoneNumber will be formatted by the OS, and shown in the prompt. It's a system prompt and we can't do anything about it.

You may however create a custom alert and show phoneNumber in your desired format before the system prompt is shown:

```
if let phoneNumber = phoneNumber, let phoneURL = NSURL(string: ("tel://" + phoneNumber)) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: ("Call " + phoneNumber + "?"), message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        UIApplication.shared.open(phoneURL as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

For more info on phone links, please check: [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)

You may find more details on URLs for Telephone Calls, how phone numbers are formatted when a telephone URL is being parsed by the mobile OS here [RFC 2806](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the response @Prateek Roy, im aware of this alert when invoking tel scheme however what i wanted to achieve is for the OS not to automatically format the phone number.

I actually tried your suggestion but i shows 2 alerts. First is the custom alert without number formatting. The other one is the system generated prompt with the formatted number. 

im suspecting that this formatting has something to do with the region set on the device but when i tried to change it , it actually does nothing.

Comment: can you enlighten me why Apple does this automatic formatting? i cant find documentation regarding this. Thanks

Comment: @Anonymous123 have edited my answer with proper links